# Update firebase without duplication

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am learner of firebase confused with data structure.

I have data structure like below

```
myApp--> news 

          --> K8ZqRIzrX6L3q-HjO8V --> title : "value title1"
                                  --> body : "value body1"
                                  --> ....

          --> K8ZqRJ1tI7onmoVX8G4 --> title : "value title2"
                                  --> body : "value body2"
                                  --> ....
```

Now I want to push more data to Firebase. I have object like bellow:

```
 [{title: "value title2", body: "value body2", ...},{title: "value title3", body: "value body3", ...}]
```

My object has duplicates. When I push to Firebase, it adds full new object with new auto generated keys. Instead I want firebase to be updated only new values and avoid duplicates.

Edited: 
I used myFirebaseRef.push(), and sample code is here,

```
                objNews.forEach(function(news){
                    myFirebaseRef.push(news,function(){
                    $('.result').append('<li><strong>' + news.title + '</strong></li>');
                    });   
                });
```

Where objNews has new data as well as the data firebase already have. What i want to achieve is push only new data from ObjNews and avoid data which firebase already have. But my code push all data in Object to firebase which results duplicates.

Comment: Unless you show the code that you've already written, it is impossible to say what you're doing wrong.

Comment: How do your updates match up with the existing data? Is `{title: "value title2", body: "value body2", ...}` meant to be an update to `K8ZqRIzrX6L3q-HjO8V`?

Comment: I have edited question adding code i used to push, but now I have solved problem comparing objNews with each item in firebase and splice data which already exists. i like to know if any other easier way. thank you

Comment: I still don't understand what defines if something is *new* or already existing. Until you clarify (for example by showing the comparison that you do), I'm voting to close.

Comment: Okey, sorry for my bad language, as I am self learner may be  i am confusing you with poor techinical terms. Let me try to explain once again and for last time :). I am using firebase to store NEWS/ARTICLES. bsically  this each NEWS contains TITLE,  BODY(text)  etc. in firebase I have created a child with the name "news". I was successfully pushed first set of NEWS to firebase using .push(), there were many NEWS, I had strored all NEWS in javascript array object with name  "objNews", Using .forEach() statement pushed one by one to firebase(code given above in question),

Comment: firebase created unique keys for each news. Every things till this stage was okey for me.  Now I have same javascript object which is objNews which is updated with many new NEWS contents, when i say new i meant new set of datas appended to old object(for eg. when I pushed objNews for first time it was containing NEWS of yesterday and now it contains NEWS of yesterday PLUS NEWS of today). So now my array object "objNews"  has contents which already pushed to firebase and new set of NEWS. I only want to push new NEWS data from "objNews", and skip those I have already pushed in first attempt.

Comment: may be I am looking for sync between objNews and firebase db. Thank you for you reply, appreaciate you responded to my question.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have a JavaScript array with news articles:

```
[
  {title: "value title2", body: "value body2", ...},
  {title: "value title3", body: "value body3", ...}
]
```

And you want to send this array to Firebase and then be able to update the values in the array and send the updates to Firebase.

**This is an anti-pattern, don't do this!**

The trick is in knowing which array index is mapped to which push-id in Firebase.

```
var keysByIndex = {};
objNews.forEach(function(news, index){
    var newRef = myFirebaseRef.push(news);
    keysByIndex[index] = newRef.key();
});
```

Now you can check if the object has already been stored in Firebase and if so, update it:

```
var keysByIndex = {};
objNews.forEach(function(news, index){
    if (keysByIndex[index]) {
        var newRef = myFirebaseRef.push(news);
        keysByIndex[index] = newRef.key();
    }
    else {
        myFirebaseRef.child(keysByIndex[index]).update(news);
    }
});
```

There are an incredible number of pitfalls with this approach.

**This is a better way to deal with this scenario.**

I *highly* recommend that you take the opposite approach: make all your write operations in Firebase and then listen to an array of data from there. This is sometimes called a uni-directional flow (since all data flows in a single continuous loop) or the [command-query segregation principle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

It works like this:

```
your app                        Firebase
                                  +-+
 -------- send write command -->  | |
 +-+                              | |
 |s|                              |s|
 |t|                              |t|
 |a|                              |a|
 |t|  <-- listen for changes ---  |t|
 |e|                              |e|
 +-+                              | |
                                  +-+
```

In this scenario, the local application state (the `objNews` in your scenario) comes from listening to Firebase. All changes are written to Firebase, instead of to the local array.

A small snippet of how you could use this. I'll just create/update DOM elements, since that's what your code was also doing:

```
myFirebaseRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  // a news article was added, add it to the HTML
  var key = snapshot.key();
  var news = snapshot.val();
  $('.result').append('<li id="'+key+'"><strong>' + news.title + '</strong></li>');
})
myFirebaseRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
  // a news article was changed, update the HTML for it 
  var key = snapshot.key();
  var news = snapshot.val();
  $('#'+key).html('<li id="'+key+'"><strong>' + news.title + '</strong></li>');
})
myFirebaseRef.on('child_removed', function(snapshot) {
  // a news article was remove, remove the HTML for it 
  var key = snapshot.key();
  var element = document.getElementById(key);
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
})
```

My jQuery is a bit rusty, so there might be some syntax errors in there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer tought me three event calls, Definetly you have spent time for creating that diagram to shoe how it works :), thank you I have used below code to push only new News array to firebase i know its mess, please tell me if any  easiest method for this.

Comment: var newNews= objNews;
myFirebaseRef.once("value",function(snapshot){                    
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
        objNews.forEach(function(news){ 
            if(childSnapshot.val().title==news.title){
                $.each(newNews,function(i){
                    if(newNews[i].title==childSnapshot.val().title){
                        newNews.splice(i,1);
                        return false;
                    }              
                });
            }
        });
    });
newNews.forEach(function(news){
myFirebaseRef.push(news);   
});
});